# How to disable ctrl + scroll zoom in Lubuntu or openbox

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, openbox

If are you in Google Chrome, Firefox or a software that have the zoom functionality, when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SCROLL UP</kbd>/<kbd>DOWN</kbd>` or <kbd>TOUCHPAD SCROLL</kbd> the page increase/decrease the zoom how to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` or `rc.xml` at:

```
 <mouse>
    ....
    <context name="Frame">
     .......
```

1. set this:

   ```
   <!-- prevent that the browsers do zoom in/out when navigating with ctrl + scroll up/down -->
   <mousebind button="C-Up" action="Click" >
           <action name="Focus"/>
   </mousebind>
   <mousebind button="C-Down" action="Click" >
           <action name="Focus"/>
   </mousebind>
   ```
2. Type `openbox --reconfigure` in terminal to check the changes, if the changes has broken it will validate.

It's all.

Comment: That will work but in the same login you will need to apply openbox --reconfigure. To apply the settings in the same login.  Which is the same for any changes to the openbox config file. I think this is a good thing as if there is error with the xml it will not apply and end up with totally broken window management.

Comment: Not works anymore on google chrome 51.0.2704.79 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Use [block-scroll-mod-x11](https://github.com/jarnos/block-scroll-mod-x11). That will disable zooming only, if you press a modifier key after scrolling has started.